# Como dar foco para um aba especifica do navegador a partir de uma verificação php

Tags: php

Gostaria que a partir de um tempo definido caso o usuário tenha selecionado uma outra aba, ou esteja vendo outra coisa no navegador(Email), o pagina do sistema seja selecionada como se estivesse trocado de aba, endo o usuário tem um tempo limite de retorno, assim eu forçaria o usuário é retornar para o sistema e realizar as suas atividades obrigatórias

Comment: Isso é uma intrusão muito grande - é como tirar o livro que estou lendo... Pelo que sei não é permitido alterar a aba que o usuário está. Use um sistema sonoro ou as notificações do Chrome.

Comment: Crie um temporizador e execute um áudio apos o tempo determinado, assim que o áudio iniciar o ícone do mesmo ira aparecer na aba. (chrome)

Comment: como eu faria isso ? teria uma outra sugestão para chamar a atenção do usuário ?

Comment: Desculpe, mas o que isso tem a ver com PHP? Se você quiser chamar a atenção do usuário para uma outra aba, é só usar um ``alert`` do javascript. Ou então pode animar o título (``document.title``) ou usar notificações, como o Papa Charlie disse.

Answer (score 1):

**Não** é possível fazer mudança de aba, devido a precauções de segurança do browser.

Mas, de qualquer forma caso te ajude, há como detectar se a pagina do sistema é ou não a pagina ativa no momento, através da [Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API).

Adicione o código abaixo:

```
<script>
var vis = (function(){
    var stateKey, eventKey, keys = {
        hidden: "visibilitychange",
        webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
        mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
        msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
    };
    for (stateKey in keys) {
        if (stateKey in document) {
            eventKey = keys[stateKey];
            break;
        }
    }
    return function(c) {
        if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
        return !document[stateKey];
    }
})();
</script>
```

Com isso, você consegue recuperar o status da página da seguinte forma:

```
<script>
var visible = vis();
</script>
```

E sua variável `visible` passará a conter o valor `'Visible'` ou `'Not visible'` de acordo com o status da pagina ativa no momento.

Se quiser ver o funcionamento tem uma [página de demonstração](http://dystroy.org/demos/vis-en.html) que muda o título da pagina quando ela está focada/desfocada.

Espero ter ajudado.

*[Lembrando que o código acima refere-se a javascript e não php como fala na pergunta]*

Answer (score 0):

se você abrir uma página através da sua, como por exemplo via javascript com window.open, pode setar um nome a ela, e dar foco acionando-a pelo nome. Caso seja uma página q você conheça o name também pode fazer o window.elemento.focus() chamando a window q deseje.